# Metric Spaces: The dist function

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-writing, proof-verification

Given that $A$ is defined as non-empty subset of $(X,d)$

The distance function is defined as such:

$dist(x,A)=$ inf $_{y\in A} \lbrace d(x,y) \rbrace $

Given the above we are asked to prove the following:

$ x \in A \Rightarrow dist(x, A ) =0$.

This seems so obvious  given the following property of metric spaces :

$ d(x ,y)= 0 \iff x=y   $ $\forall x ,y \in  X $

However, I'm not quite sure what constitutes a rigorous proof in these cases.

Comment: you did right: $x$ is the only element of $A$ (if $A=\{x\}$) so you have to check only one case for $y\in A$: $y=x$

Comment: Hint: For every $x \in X$, $x \geq \inf X$, pretty much by the definition of the infimum. And if for all $x \in X$ you have $x \geq a$, then $\inf X \geq a$. (But note that the second theorem is *wrong* if you replace $\geq$ by $>$)

Comment: @fgp that helps a lot.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of them are very obvious

**First part:**
 $$\inf_{y\in\{x\}}\{d(x,y)\}=\inf_{y=x}\{d(x,y)\}=d(x,x)=0$$

**Second part:**

Fix $x\in A$. Because $d(x,x)\in\{d(x,y):\ y\in A\}$  so
$$\{d(x,x)\}\subset\{d(x,y):\ y\in A\}$$ 
and consequently $$0\leq d(x,A)=\inf \{d(x,y):\ y\in A\}\leq \inf \{d(x,x)\}=d(x,x)=0$$
Hence $d(x,A)=0$

Comment: And the 2nd part?

Comment: For understanding, why is inf $\lbrace d(x,y) |  y \in A\rbrace \leq $inf$ { d(x,x) } $

Comment: When $A\subset B$  then $\inf B\leq \inf A$.

Comment: Of course facepalm.